# Posting to self-hosted WordPress from Tweetie (or other Twitter Clients)

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Is there a plugin yet that allows me to post to my self-hosted WordPress install from Tweetie or another Twitter client?

I know WordPress.com can do this, I just want to do this on my own blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to find something to do this. Instead I am now just using the WordPress app and posting my tweets in the title and have those auto-post to Twitter. Not quite as slick, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Tweetie but you can use the **[Twitter Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/)** wordpress plugin to show your tweets.

Comment: That allows posting from WordPress, but not Tweetie (the last I looked anyway).

Comment: You can configure Twitter Tools to create a post of every tweet you create - indirectly allowing you to post from a twitter-client. However you would still be limited to 140 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [ping.fm](http://ping.fm/) instead. Post it to broadcast to both twitter and your wordpress blog.

However, if you don't want to use ping.fm, you can always fetch RSS from twitter and have it shown as blogpost on your wordpress using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/).